# Split on comma, but only when not in double quoted

Tags: perl, split

How can i split the below string in array?
I tried the split() but its also spliting the bouble quoted string....however i don't want to split bouble quoted string.

```
Apple,"String1,String2",Abcd,EFGH,XYZ
```

the output should be like :

```
Apple
"String,String2"
Abcd
EFGH
XYZ
```

Comment: Are you processing a CSV file? Use [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV).

Comment: @choroba  `Text::CSV` is not installed by default in *perl-base* package, while `Text::ParseWords` does the job **and** is part of *perl-base*. See `perldoc perlfaq4` (or `man perlfaq4`)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Text::CSV;

my $parser = Text::CSV->new;
$parser->parse(qq(Apple,"String1,String2",Abcd,EFGH,XYZ));
say join "---", $parser->fields;
```

Output:

```
Apple---String1,String2---Abcd---EFGH---XYZ
```

Comment: `Text::CSV` seem not installed by default in my `perl-base` package, while `Text::ParseWords` does the job and is part of `perl-base`.